# After Redis cluster reshard, lots of non contiguous slots assigned to a node

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I created a redis cluster with three nodes:

```
~ redis-3.2.10/src/redis-trib.rb create 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002
```

I then added a fourth node and resharded to make the slot allocation even:

```
~ redis-3.2.10/src/redis-trib.rb add-node 127.0.0.1:7003 127.0.0.1:7000
~ redis-3.2.10/src/redis-trib.rb reshard --timeout 60000  127.0.0.1:7000
...
How many slots do you want to move (from 1 to 16384)? 4096
...
Source node #1:all
...
redis-3.2.10/src/redis-trib.rb check 127.0.0.1:7000
>>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 127.0.0.1:7000)
M: 29fbb7e5f93eac22a224c14d4070139919bb0a5e 127.0.0.1:7000
   slots:1365-5460 (4096 slots) master
   0 additional replica(s)
M: c90c9f590bb48d328f3eed2fc96af3a7d9cb0f25 127.0.0.1:7003
   slots:0-1364,5461-6826,10923-12287 (4096 slots) master
   0 additional replica(s)
M: 970b3145574a4f38bbe10548bf6b80f8fdc2854d 127.0.0.1:7001
   slots:6827-10922 (4096 slots) master
   0 additional replica(s)
M: 2cc0922fcfb3e619b6d733e054dd249a4b6137bf 127.0.0.1:7002
   slots:12288-16383 (4096 slots) master
   0 additional replica(s)
[OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
>>> Check for open slots...
>>> Check slots coverage...
[OK] All 16384 slots covered.
```

Then if you scale back down, reshard the slots back from the :7003 node to the remaining three, you end up with something like:

```
>>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 127.0.0.1:7000)
M: 29fbb7e5f93eac22a224c14d4070139919bb0a5e 127.0.0.1:7000
   slots:1365-5460,12288-13652 (5461 slots) master
   0 additional replica(s)
M: 970b3145574a4f38bbe10548bf6b80f8fdc2854d 127.0.0.1:7001
   slots:0-1364,5461-6826,10923-12287,13653-15017 (5461 slots) master
   0 additional replica(s)
M: 2cc0922fcfb3e619b6d733e054dd249a4b6137bf 127.0.0.1:7002
   slots:6827-10922,15018-16383 (5462 slots) master
   0 additional replica(s)
M: c90c9f590bb48d328f3eed2fc96af3a7d9cb0f25 127.0.0.1:7003
   slots: (0 slots) master
   0 additional replica(s)
[OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.
>>> Check for open slots...
>>> Check slots coverage...
[OK] All 16384 slots covered.
```

The :7001 node has 4 different groups of hash slots assigned to it. After subsequent resharding this 'fragmentation' of hash slots seems to increase.

Could it ever become a problem (to performance or otherwise) having more and more fragmentation of hash slots?

Comment: why last node has 0 slots ?

Comment: Because I had just reassigned all slots away from that node to the remaining three, in anticipation of removing it from the cluster.

Comment: If you want to consecutive slots to each node then first make single node cluster then add other node in it . I have done same thing.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Good to know you can at least ‘reset’ in that way

Comment: did you  do same ?

Comment: Almost, I had a three node cluster with lots of slot fragmentation, from two of the nodes I assigned all of their slots to the other node so that all slots existed on a single node, then I balanced out the slots across the other two nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK no - hash slots' "fragmentation" is negligible in terms of any meaningful overheads. Some intuition:

- Small range (16K)
- Resharding isn't a frequent operation
- Internally, Redis uses bitmaps to manage the slot mapping, so regardless of the actual slots' distribution accessing these bitmaps is done in constant time.

Comment: Could it also depend on the client? I suppose in theory a badly written client might not be achieving constant time for its slot mapping cache?

Comment: Definitely, that's a very good point. If the client is intelligent enough to keep its own copy of the topology (this isn't a mandatory requirement), it may be implemented in a less than optimal fashion and could suffer from all kinds of issues :)

Comment: Sound great ! Then you  should accept  my answer mentioned
 below.

Answer (score 0):

First Create Single node cluster.
For that you need to edit redis_trib.rb file for min 3 node required validation.

After creating single node cluster just add other nodes and add consecutive slots in new node. 
By this way you will get what you want.